# How to call Parameterized Stored Procedure in C# (ASP.Net)?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, stored-procedures, web-applications

I am developing a web application in which I want that the user enters a string in a textbox and on click of search button; it will search the entire database for a user entered string (i.e it will display the Database name, Schema Name, Table name,Column Name and Record Name in a grid view).

I had already written stored procedure in SQL and executed it successfully where stored procedure search for entered string in database and insert the data in a table named `tempdb.dbo.result`.

Here is my stored procedure for string search in a database:

```
Use tempdb
GO

Create Table Result
(
    [Sno] int identity(1,1),
    [Database Name] sysname,
    [Schema Name] sysname,
    [Table Name] sysname,
    [Column Name] sysname,
    [Record Name] varchar(Max)
)

USE TestDB2
GO

CREATE PROCEDURE Find_Record_Across_Tables_Proc
     @Database sysname,
     @Schema sysname,
     @Table sysname,
     @String VARCHAR(Max)
AS
    DECLARE @SqlString varchar(Max)
    DECLARE @Table_Schema sysname
    DECLARE @Table_Name sysname
    DECLARE @Column_Name sysname

    --Declare Cursor
    SET @SqlString = 'DECLARE String_cursor CURSOR FOR
    Select TABLE_SCHEMA, TABLE_NAME ,COLUMN_NAME from
    ' + @Database +'.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
    Where DATA_TYPE IN (''text'',''ntext'',''varchar''
    ,''nvarchar'',''char'',''nchar'')'

    --Filter schema name
    IF @schema IS NOT NULL
    Begin
        SET @SqlString = @SqlString + ' And TABLE_SCHEMA=''' + @Schema + ''''
    End

    --Filter table name
    IF @table IS NOT NULL
    Begin
        SET @SqlString = @SqlString + ' And TABLE_NAME=''' + @table + ''''
    End

    Print @SqlString
    EXEC (@SqlString)

OPEN String_cursor

FETCH NEXT FROM String_cursor
INTO @Table_Schema, @Table_Name, @Column_Name

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
SET @SqlString = 'IF EXISTS(SELECT ' + QUOTENAME(@Column_Name)
+ ' FROM ' + @Database + '.' + QUOTENAME(@Table_Schema)
+ '.' + QUOTENAME(@Table_Name)
+ ' WHERE ' + QUOTENAME(@Column_Name)
+ ' Like ''%' + @string + '%'')
Insert into tempdb.dbo.result
([Database Name],[Schema Name]
,[Table Name],[Column Name],[Record Name])
SELECT ''' + QUOTENAME(@Database) + ''','''
+ QUOTENAME(@Table_Schema) + ''','''
+ QUOTENAME(@Table_Name) + ''',''''
+ ''' + QUOTENAME(@Column_Name)
+ ''',' + QUOTENAME(@Column_Name)
+ ' FROM ' + @Database + '.'
+ QUOTENAME(@Table_Schema)
+ '.' + QUOTENAME(@Table_Name)
+ ' WHERE ' + QUOTENAME(@Column_Name)
+ ' Like ''%' + @string + '%'''
Print @SqlString
EXEC (@SqlString)

FETCH NEXT FROM String_cursor
INTO @Table_Schema, @Table_Name, @Column_Name

END
CLOSE String_cursor
DEALLOCATE String_cursor
GO
```

I had successfully executed this stored procedure in SQL through these commands:

```
Use TestDB2
GO

EXEC Find_Record_Across_Tables_Proc
'TestDB2(My database name)', NULL, NULL ,'string to be searched'
GO

Select * from tempdb.dbo.result
GO
```

Now whenever I execute (call) this parameterized stored procedure from a web application, the compiler shows no exception on calling the stored procedure, but it will only run the select query in `BindGrid()`.

Here is the my code for that:

```
public partial class WebForm1 : System.Web.UI.Page
{
     DataSet ds = new DataSet();
     SqlConnection con;

     protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
     {
     }

     protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
     {
         String value = TextBox1.Text.ToString();

         con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MyDbConn"].ConnectionString);
         con.Open(); 

         SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Find_Record_Across_Tables_Proc", con);
         cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

         cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Database", "TestDB2");
         cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Schema", "NULL");
         cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Table", "NULL");
         cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@String", value);

         cmd.ExecuteNonQuery(); 
         con.Close();

         this.BindGrid();
     }

     private void BindGrid()
     {
         string constr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MyDbConn"].ConnectionString;

         using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(constr))
         {
             using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Select * from tempdb.dbo.result"))
             {
                    using (SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter())
                    {
                        cmd.Connection = con;
                        sda.SelectCommand = cmd;
                        using (DataTable dt = new DataTable())
                        {
                            sda.Fill(dt);
                            GridView1.DataSource = dt;
                            GridView1.DataBind();
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: what error u are getting?

Comment: it gives me no error ,no exception. But on execution It will executes  BindGrid() successfully and displays the result in grid view from using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Select * from tempdb.dbo.result"))

Comment: are you able to insert data into he DB?

Comment: I have written the insert command inside the SP. and It's executing successfully whenver I execute them through SQL

Comment: i.e. the tempdb.dbo.result Table successfully displays the Database name, Schema Name, Table name,Column Name and Record Name where the entered string present

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `button_Click` for the `cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();`  just assign a int value `i`

Ex:

```
 int i =cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
 if(i>0)
 {
     this.BindGrid();
 }
```

**Update**
Note :  i see you are passing the DB and also Schema as a parameter in the procedure but in the connection string you will be defining this, It will be useful when you are doing from the SQL but while coming to the application you need not use them because you will be stating the web-config which database and schema , so that it will be a redundant .

Comment: I have checked but now it skips the if portion. and this statement [int i =cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();] gives -1 value to i

Comment: @Iqraa ah got it

Comment: @Iqraa    `String value = TextBox1.Text.ToString();` in this you dont need to cast it tostring and also , are you following the same order while passing the values to the stored procedure , it should be in same order and same Name (i mean case sensitive)

Comment: Yes I am passing the values in the correct order to SP

Comment: @Iqraa i see you are passing the DB and also Schema as a prameter in the procedure but in the connection string you will be defining this , what is the reason for stating them here?

Comment: if I will not add these statements the compiles throws an exception "SP required the parameter '@database' and '@Schema' which are not specified". and basically here the parameter '@database' contains the name of database in which I have to search the entered string.

Comment: @Iqraa yes , i got your point , it will be usefull when you are doing from the SQL but while coming to the application you need not use them because you will be stating the web-config which database and schema , so that it will be a redundand and the C# will not execute them the way it is executing in the sql.

Comment: without these statements it will throw exception "Procedure or function 'Find_Record_Across_Tables_Proc' expects parameter '@Database', which was not supplied."

Comment: @Iqraa in your SQL also you need to remove that as a parameter

Comment: Thanks alot for your guidance. It worked with some another technique in which I have removed database and schema name.

Comment: @Iqraa i modified my answer with the update.. so that it will help for the future users